# "Hciuart.service dependency failed", Timed out waiting for device /dev/serial1

Tags: gpio, bluetooth, serial

I have the following problem:
Since I wanted to use the integrated Bluetooth module on my Raspberry Pie 3 B+, I come across the following problem:

```
Hciuart.service: Job hciuart.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Lake 'journalctl -xe for details'
```

When I entered `journalctl -xe` in ds terminal, I got the following results:

```
"Timed out waiting for device /dev/serial1"
Subject: A start job for unit dev-serial1.device has failed.
```

I have already re-updated the Bluetooth version.
The command: `systemctl show hciuart.service` displays:

```
Loaded: loaded...
Active: inactive(dead)
```

Could it be the following problem?:
Bluetooth is disabled by using serial1 as ports for RX and TX?
This is somehow related, have I read?

In addition, the Bluetooth icon is not visible, so I can't use the 'Make discoverable' feature.

The following quote found:
"The Raspberry Pi 3 uses the UART1 (ttyS0) for the GPIO port by default, while the previous Raspberry Pi models still used the UART0 for this. The UART0 (ttyAMA0) is used by software in the Pi 3 by the newly introduced Bluetooth module. However, the Pi 3's UART1 with CPU frequency, CPU load, temperature, and other attachments is often not stable enough for the operation of plug-in modules. The Pi 3 must, therefore, be reconfigured to use some plug-in modules for the GPIO port that communicate via GPIO 14/15 so that the GPIO port uses the UART0 again, as in the previous models. "
• https://wiki.fhem.de/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_3:_GPIO-Port_Module_und_Bluetooth

I think the opposite is needed.
I need the function of a school project...

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Yes, Bluetooth intermingled with UART makes a big mess.  I heard that Rpi4B has no such problem. So perhaps you can cheat by using Rpi4B.

Comment: SO there is no Chance of Fixing this issue? a Rpi4B means extra Costs...

Comment: The default Pi setup works perfectly well. Unless you have some particularly demanding role the miniUART works and is quite stable - although it is limited to 8NP. I suggest you put the settings back to default and explain what you are trying to do with the UART